# Magento2: Retrieve the payment last 4 digits and expiry date in the order email

Tags: magento2, email-templates, payment

I am trying to add payment-related information in the Order email on Magento 2. ( Last 4 digits of the card, expiry date of the card ).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that expiration date is a sensitive data that shouldn't be sent threw an email ? But may be I'm wrong. Actually you probably doesn't have any place where this data is stored.

Comment: Yes. But last 4 digit was showing in admin order page. I would like to retrieve at least this data. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

### **Yes, you can retrieve credit card details from order object.**

`$order` is of type `Magento\Sales\Model\Order`

The following methods get the credit card details:

```
$order->getPayment()->getCcExpMonth(); 
$order->getPayment()->getCcExpYear();
$order->getPayment()->getCcLast4();
```

Comment: Hi Patel , Thanks for the information. I checked this, it shows empty data.

Comment: which object ur using for order can you please tell me

Comment: Same object, that you mention on this. $order is of type Magento\Sales\Model\Order  . I have used this on Observer (email_order_set_template_vars_before) and payment gateway Stripes.